# Change animation speed with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, jquery-animate

```
$("a").hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({left: '-500px'}, 'slow');
);
```

I use this code to animate position of the link. I move it to the left corner with `slow` animation speed.

How do I change speed of this animation to `fast`, when link is clicked?

We should get:

- `slow` animation when link is hovered.
- `fast` when it is clicked.

The problem is, link can be already animated, when we try to click on it. What do you think?

Thanks.

Comment: you can specify the time interval as a second argument...that will take care

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("a").hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({left: '-500px'}, 'slow');
).click(function() {
    $(this).dequeue().animate({left: '-500px'}, 'fast');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $(this).stop(true).animate({left: '-500px'}, 'fast');
);
```

(Not tested)

Answer (score 0):

This might work, using `stop()` to stop any animation already running.

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $(this).stop()
    $(this).animate({left: '-500px'}, 'fast');
);
```